# Estimate area of the region

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions

A unknown function defines a region in 2D. Each variable is constrained to [0,1] interval. Function returns 1 if the co-ordinates in 2D belong to the region else returns 0. How do I calculate the area of the region?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered. The general problem you're trying to solve is called 'classification'. You'd have to provide more details about your specific problem before we can help think about solutions.

Comment: @user20160 I understood the question entirely differently, as being one about Monte-Carlo estimation, not classification.

Comment: @AmiTavory Our interpretations were different because the question was edited between the times we each read it. The edited version is clearer, and I agree that it's about integration.

Comment: @user20160 Ah, I see that now. Your comment probably helped clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as [*Monte-Carlo area estimation*](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3220/2008su/slides/montecarlointegration.pdf).

If the true size of the area is $s$, and noting that the bounding square has area 1, the probability of a random point to be in the area is $s$ also.

Suppose you generate $n$ random points - each generated uniformly within the bounding square - and find that $m$ of them are inside the area. an estimate for the area could be $s = \frac{m}{n}$. To find a bound on the estimation error, you can use the [Chernoff Bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_.28relative_error.29).